# ASP.NET textboxes doesn't work in Bootstrap template

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i am using bootstrap template so bootstrap blocking asp.net textbox elements. I can't insert any record to database. Textboxes just returns null value.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box-menu-footer4">
<div class="input-prepend">       
<input type="text" id="" name="" placeholder="E-mail address ...">
<span class="add-on"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span></div>
<input type="submit" value="" class="btn btn-large" /></div>
```

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubscribe" OnClick="btnSubscribe_Click" runat="server" />
```

**C#**

```
string RegisterDate = "";
txtEmail.Text = "";
bool Statu = true;
bool RegisterStatu = false;
DataAccesLayer.DAL.EBulten(txtEmail.Text, RegisterDate, RegisterStatu, Statu);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that you are resting the text box.

Change the C# code from

```
string RegisterDate = "";
txtEmail.Text = "";
bool Statu = true;
bool RegisterStatu = false;
DataAccesLayer.DAL.EBulten(txtEmail.Text, RegisterDate, RegisterStatu, Statu);
```

To:

```
string RegisterDate = "";
bool Statu = true;
bool RegisterStatu = false;
DataAccesLayer.DAL.EBulten(txtEmail.Text, RegisterDate, RegisterStatu, Statu);
```

Just to note that bootstrap does not make any different to how form works. It only effect the look and feel.